# c++ code behaves abnormally when the return value is missing

Tags: c++

GCC 9.2.1 gives a warning that there is "no return statement in function returning non-void", however, the code does compile (I compiled with flags -O3 and -finline-functions).

I expected the program to have no output, as the condition for the while loop should evaluate to false. However, I got the following output from the program (printed in the while loop):

"it != mMap.end(): 0"

The output is particularly odd, given that the printed value (i.e., 0 or "false") is also the condition for the while loop.

After the print, the program segfaults because the iterator becomes invalid (via `it++` in the while loop that should never have executed).

I guess this can all be chalked up to the missing return value. But, I find it surprising that the code behaves so pathologically simply because a return value isn't supplied. I'd appreciate any insight into understanding what's happening at a deeper level.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>

struct Test
{
  int Dummy (void) const
  {
    std::tr1::unordered_map<int, int>::const_iterator it = mMap.begin();
    while (it != mMap.end())
    {   
      std::cout << "it != mMap.end(): " << (it != mMap.end()) << std::endl;
      it++;
    }   
  }
  std::tr1::unordered_map<int, int> mMap;
};

int main (void)
{
  Test test;
  test.Dummy();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: _behaves abnormally when the return value is missing_ … Yes. That does not surprise me at all, actually.

Comment: That's what *undefined behavior* does to a program - it can behave very weirdly

Comment: Why do you want to understand undefined behavior?  You promised the compiler you would return a `int`.  By breaking that promise the compiler is free to do whatever it wants.

Comment: C++ is not a nanny language.  If you break the rules, the compiler can do strange things, or may appear to work as intended.  Nanny languages protect you from making these kinds of mistakes, but at the expense of checking for those mistakes.  C++ presumes you provide valid code to the compiler.  If you provide invalid code to the compiler, you may want to enable all the compiler warnings, so the compiler has a chance at providing you with feedback about the suspicious code constructs.

Comment: This article will explain why UB can do literally whatever it wants and how that manifests itself: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: The title of the thread *c++ code behaves abnormally when the return value is missing* -- well...um yes, of course.  Maybe you've used other languages where if you do something wrong, you're told you did something wrong, like throw an exception (like Java).  This is not so with C++.

Comment: There are many useful compiler warnings that are off by default.  Here is my minimum warning list I use for all compiles:   "-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic 
-Werror=vla -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion 
-Wsign-compare   -Wsign-promo -Wpointer-arith -Wunused -Wold-style-cast    
-Woverloaded-virtual -Wsequence-point -Wdelete-incomplete -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wmisleading-indentation -Wunreachable-code   -Wnon-virtual-dtor.    All though missing from this list, my g++ compiler _does_ report "warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]"

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: @2785528 I use a very similar list, but also add `-Werror` so I never accidentally commit code with warnings but is forced to fix them all.

Answer (score 3):

Returning from a non-`void` function without supplying a return value is underfined behavior, and therefore the compiler can do whatever it wants.

What the compiler has done in this case in particular, seems to be that it has spotted that skipping the loop would trigger UB and therefore assumes the loop is entered at least once. Therefore it assumes that it can safely enter the loop without checking the condition as the compiler trusts that the author of the program did not invoke any undefined behavior.

This is of course speculation from my part.

Comment: Compiler assumes the `while` loop has a `return` statement inside, and doesn't bother checking it. This is great speculation!

Answer (score 0):

You should turn on warnings using `-Wextra` and `-Wall` in `gcc` which will e.g. enable the warning [`Control reaches the end of a non-void function`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB23S_1.1.0.2020/common/m1rhnvf.html) so you will hopefully not forget about fixing stuff like that. To enforce it, enable the compiler flag `-Werror`.

Not returning a value invokes undefined behavior so the compiler is allowed to either return a garbage value or crash your program (this is what `clang` typically does) if the function returns. This is bad and you should never keep broken code like that. For additional insight you can use a disassembler and see what your compiler did at the end of the function.